# Что в этом случае значит параметр TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, равный константе?

Tags: c#, winapi

Что в этом случае значит параметр TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, равный константе? 
        public const Int32 TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = 2;
        IntPtr hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS в данном случае означает, что в снэпшоте будут все процессы. Спасибо что почитали MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682489(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: а почему равен именно 2?

Comment: Потому что так решил Microsoft